# Update one column of a table with column of another table (one to many relationship)

Tags: mysql, sql

Thank you for your time.

Here is what i want to do. I want to update the column of one table with the information of another table.

tableA

```
in_number
date
```

tableB

```
in_number
anchor_date
```

Now tableA, has on in_number per tuple. But tableB has several in_number. Which it has a one-to-many relationship. Regardless, I want update the anchor_date in tableB with the date in tableA when in_number in both tables match. How can i do this?

I tried this

```
UPDATE TableB t1, tableA t2
    SET t1.anchor_date= t2.date 
    WHERE t2.in_number = t1.in_number;
```

But this only updates one row per in_number.

Please help

Comment: Nothing in your query is limiting the update to one row per `in_number`.  You are misinterpreting the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should probably be looking up the date using a `join` in a `select` query, rather than duplicating the data across tables.  Let me assume that you have a good reason for the data duplication.

Second, your query should work, but it would be better written using explicit `join` syntax:

```
UPDATE TableB b JOIN
       TableA a
       USING (in_number)
    SET b.anchor_date = a.date ;
```

Comment: Can this be done with ALTER COLUMN? this is not working for me for some reason

Comment: @freecks . . . No `alter column` does not assign values to columns in this way.

Comment: I miss interpreted the results of the columns that were changed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below SQL query.

Update b set anchor_date = a.date
From tableb b 
Inner join tablea a
On a.in_number = b.in_number